# How do I list the files having particular strings from group of directories in bash?

Tags: linux, shell

I want to list files having EXACT strings like "hello", "how" and "todo" from  a directory (which is having multiple directories). Also I want to list c(.c) and cpp (.cpp) files only. 
I have tried with `grep -R` (`grep -R "hello" /home`) but not satisfied. Please help me to enhance my `grep -R` command or any alternate way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, what is the problem with `grep -R` ?

Comment: `find . -name "*.c" -o -name "*.cpp" -exec egrep 'hello|how|todo' {} \;` should make it, but I don't know why it does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to find files, a good start is usually to use `find`.

if you want to find all `.cpp` and `.-c` files that contain the strings "hello", "how" or "todo" in their content, use something like:

```
find /home \( -name "*.c" -or -name "*.cpp" \) \
    -exec egrep -l "(hello|how|todo)" \{\} \;
```

if instead you want to find all `.cpp` and `.-c` files that contain the strings "hello", "how" or "todo" in their filenames, use something like:

```
find /home                                                       \
   \( \( -name "*.c" -or -name "*.cpp" \)                        \
      -and                                                       \
      \( -name "*hello*" -or -name "*how*" -or -name "*todo*" \) \
   \)
```

there is a bit of quoting (using `\`) involved, as `()`, `{}` and `;` are considered special characters by the shell...

Comment: wow!!  this helps.. Thanks a lot.. Thank you umläute for your wonderful answer :)

Comment: How to get exact string here? Which option I should choose? -v?

Comment: what do you mean by *exact*? it is still unclear to me whether you want to match the filename or the content of the file. all my examples will only match *exactly* 'hello', 'how' and 'todo', they will *not* match 'cello', 'cow' and 'tada'.

Comment: I meant the strings which we are looking for, here am getting helloworlrd instead of hello alone. but I need only files having the exact string "hello" only; I have tried with option -x ( -exec egrep  -lx). But no use!

Comment: i have two examples; one is using `find` alone, the other one using `find` and `grep`; which one are you referring to?

Comment: first one, find and egrep.

Comment: if you want to match full words (e.g. searching for the full wordd "hello" will match "say hello to mama", but *not* "helloworld") use the `-w` flag; if you want to match lines that *only* contain the given word, use the beginning-of-line (`^`) and end-of-line (`$`) markers in regexes: `"^(hello|how|todo)$"`

Answer (score 0):

In fact grep itself would be fine for this.

However I would strongly suggest **ack-grep**. It is a good alternative to grep which just suit your need.

You can find it [here](http://beyondgrep.com/)

With ack-grep it is just as simple as

```
ack-grep --cc --cpp "(hello|how|todo)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the followings:

```
      grep -rn --include={*.c,*.cpp} yourdirectory -e ^h[a-z]*
```

This will search through all the files which have .c and .cpp extensions and finds patterns starts with h (you need to prepare you own to meet your need) from your specified directory.